# How to run function of another controller with base_url specified in config.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, config, base-url

I have controller `welcome` below that redirect to function of another controller in `controllers/auth/login.php`

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
}

function index() {
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login');
    } else {
        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
    }
}
```

Here, the `config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

it work well. But when i specified the base_url in config file into:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cilog/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

`Object not found`. why it be? but it work again when i specified `index_page` into `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the way CodeIgniter handles it's URL's. I'm not actually sure why Codeigniter does this, but they include `index.php` in there URL.

So your URL would look something like `http://localhost/cilog/index.php/auth/login`

You can either rewrite your `.htaccess` file to remove the `index.php` by putting this in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and keep your `$config['base_url']` set too `"http://localhost/cilog/"`

OR

specify both a `$config['base_url']` and `$config['index_page']`

See here for more info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html (Removing the index.php file)